SQLite Escape ampersand (&) within a table name in SELECT query
Is there a way to escape an ampersand (&) within a column name in a SELECT query?
For example, I have a column called 'JACK&JILL' in an existing table. When I do a SELECT * on the table, all columns are present, if I try to run SELECT JACK&JILL, it says there is no column called JACK&JILL
Do you have any ideas on how to escape the ampersand (&)?
select jack&jill
from    (
        select 'test' as "jack&jill"
        )


Took a bit of googling:-
select ([jack&jill])
from    (
        select 'test' as "jack&jill"
        )


The round brackets aren't needed, the square ones are enough. You could have used double quotes, as well.
